# Find element with the same title and return class-element

Tags: swift, class

The Class Book is what I'm struggling on. The goal is to turn the exam block to true.

I try to compare the title of every book in the liste-array with the title I´m searching for. If it´s found the function should output the book-element and if not, return nil.

This is what I currently have:

```
    class Book {
    var title:String;
    var isbn:String;
    var price:Float;

    public init(_ title:String, _ isbn:String, _ price:Float) {
        self.title=title;
        self.isbn=isbn;
        self.price=price;
    }
}

//findBookWithTitle should output the first element with the same title.

func findBookWithTitle(_ title:String, inListe liste:[Book]) -> Book? {
    var data=liste;
    var stitle=title;
    var memory:Int=0;

    for i in 0..<data.count{

        if data[i].title==stitle{
            memory=i;
        }else{
            return nil;
        }
    }

    return data[memory]
}


//exam block
let daten=[Book("Book A","ISBN A",12),Book("Buch B","ISBN B",14),Book("Book C","ISBN C",17)];
let a1a = findBookWithTitle("Book C", inListe: daten) === daten[2];
let a1b = findBookWithTitle("Book A", inListe: daten) === daten[0];
let a1c = findBookWithTitle("Testbook", inListe: daten) === nil;
let a1 = a1a && a1b && a1c;
```

I don´t have any errors and don't know where to start fixing the problem.

Comment: It is simply `if let book = liste.first(where: { $0.title == title }) { return book }
return nil`

Comment: Or just `return liste.first(where: { $0.title == title })` :)

Comment: Unrelated, but note you don't need to end every statement with a semicolon.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I know. Its a bad habit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because you `return nil` as soon as a non-matching book title is encountered during the enumeration.

The correct approach is to return as soon as a book with a matching title is found, and to return `nil` if no matching book was found during
the enumeration:

```
func findBookWithTitle(_ title:String, inListe liste:[Book]) -> Book? {

    for i in 0..<liste.count {
        if liste[i].title == title {
            return liste[i]
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

(Note that there is no need to make variable copies of all the parameters.)

As already suggested above, this can be simplified to

```
func findBookWithTitle(_ title:String, inListe liste:[Book]) -> Book? {
    return liste.first(where: { $0.title == title })
}
```

using the [`first(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1849238-first) method for arrays (or more generally, for sequences).

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe its that simple :D